# Tokudb buggy and plugin gone missing causing mysql to stop starting?

Tags: mysql, percona-server, tokudb

I have actually installed percona mysql and trying to move from oracle mysql. I have been using innodb for quite some time. I heard and read a lot of about tokudb being able to support large db etc. So I did try to give it a try. It has been working fine suddenly today I run yum update and it stopped working.

Below is my mysqld.cnf

```
# Percona Server template configuration

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
#default-storage-engine=tokudb
```

Initially I made tokudb as my default storage after the update everything is messed and I had comment this line #default-storage-engine=tokudb only then my mysql started.

Here is how my updates looks when I ran the yum update.

```
 Updating   : Percona-Server-shared-compat-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64      1/10
  Updating   : Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             2/10
  Updating   : Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             3/10
  Updating   : Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             4/10
 -------------
   *  The suggested mysql options and settings are in /etc/percona-server.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
   *  If you want to use mysqld.cnf as default configuration file please make backup of /etc/my.cnf
   *  Once it is done please execute the following commands:
 rm -rf /etc/my.cnf
 update-alternatives --install /etc/my.cnf my.cnf "/etc/percona-server.cnf" 200
 -------------
Percona Server is distributed with several useful UDF (User Defined Function) from Percona Toolkit.
Run the following commands to create these functions:
mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv1a_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv1a_udf.so'"
mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv_udf.so'"
mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION murmur_hash RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libmurmur_udf.so'"
See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/management/udf_percona_toolkit.html for more details
  Updating   : Percona-Server-tokudb-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             5/10
  Cleanup    : Percona-Server-tokudb-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64             6/10
  Cleanup    : Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64             7/10
  Cleanup    : Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64             8/10
  Cleanup    : Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64             9/10
  Cleanup    : Percona-Server-shared-compat-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64     10/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-tokudb-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             1/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             2/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             3/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-shared-compat-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64      4/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.18-14.1.el7.x86_64             5/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64             6/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-shared-compat-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64      7/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-tokudb-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64             8/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-shared-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64             9/10
  Verifying  : Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.17-13.1.el7.x86_64            10/10

Updated:
  Percona-Server-client-57.x86_64 0:5.7.18-14.1.el7
  Percona-Server-server-57.x86_64 0:5.7.18-14.1.el7
  Percona-Server-shared-57.x86_64 0:5.7.18-14.1.el7
  Percona-Server-shared-compat-57.x86_64 0:5.7.18-14.1.el7
  Percona-Server-tokudb-57.x86_64 0:5.7.18-14.1.el7

Complete!
```

Here is my current mysql.log.

```
2017-05-15T06:03:04.579874Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-05-15T06:03:04.581301Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18-14) starting as process 2454 ...
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585394Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585425Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585433Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585440Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585449Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585460Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585733Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-05-15T06:03:04.585851Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-15T06:03:04.587208Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-05-15T06:03:04.591145Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-05-15T06:03:04.592947Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-05-15T06:03:04.602996Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2017-05-15T06:03:04.603164Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibdata1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-05-15T06:03:04.762580Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibdata1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-05-15T06:03:04.763040Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
2017-05-15T06:03:05.221084Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
2017-05-15T06:03:05.862770Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Created parallel doublewrite buffer at /var/lib/mysql/xb_doublewrite, size 3932160 bytes
2017-05-15T06:03:05.946047Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
2017-05-15T06:03:05.946134Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2017-05-15T06:03:05.946160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-05-15T06:03:05.946222Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-05-15T06:03:06.096069Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.096267Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2017-05-15T06:03:06.296244Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2017-05-15T06:03:06.310384Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.310410Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.310601Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.354573Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2017-05-15T06:03:06.354637Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.387884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.387937Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.421245Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: sys_virtual table created
2017-05-15T06:03:06.421303Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating zip_dict and zip_dict_cols system tables.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.454581Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: zip_dict and zip_dict_cols system tables created.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.454793Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-05-15T06:03:06.504972Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.7.18-14 started; log sequence number 0
2017-05-15T06:03:06.505428Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.510037Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2017-05-15T06:03:06.510134Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.511046Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_executed from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' doesn't exist
2017-05-15T06:03:06.511091Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.514560Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.514581Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.536783Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.536866Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.537595Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-05-15T06:03:06.537649Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.537671Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-05-15T06:03:06.537754Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.571570Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/server_cost from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.571611Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables

2017-05-15T06:03:06.572621Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/time_zone_leap_second from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.572655Z 0 [Warning] Can't open and lock time zone table: Table 'mysql.time_zone_leap_second' doesn't exist trying to live without them
2017-05-15T06:03:06.573327Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/servers from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-05-15T06:03:06.573357Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2017-05-15T06:03:06.582207Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-05-15T06:03:06.582530Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.18-14'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release 14, Revision 2c06f4d
2017-05-15T06:03:06.582552Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2017-05-15T06:03:06.582560Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-05-15T06:03:06.606414Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-05-15T06:10:22.125681Z 5 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-05-15T06:14:47.492149Z 8 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-05-15T06:16:05.397217Z 11 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/plugin from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue.
```

What is the best solution moving forward should I drop tokudb and just continue with innodb or is it a bug with percona itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you

- keep `default-storage-engine=tokudb` commented out
- manually specify `ENGINE=tokudb` only on tables that will benefit from it
- keep InnoDB for other tables
- file a bug report

**For specific queries**

With InnoDB (and probably TokuDB):

Select stuff (whatever is in the table) about one vehicle for one time or a time range:

```
INDEX(vehicle_id, datetime)
```

Select stuff for a particular vehicle in a particular fleet (assuming the above does not suffice):

```
INDEX(vehicle_id, fleet_id, datetime)  -- or --
INDEX(fleet_id, vehicle_id, datetime)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59066/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-tokudb-buggy-and-plugin-gone-missing-causing). Please continue there.